# Maven : Build native installer of javaFX application with Inno Setup script

Tags: java, maven, javafx, inno-setup

Recently I completed one JavaFX project and now I want to create native installer for windows. I'm using `exec-maven-plugin` to create an installer and it's working fine and generate exe file with default setting of inno setup script.

I created one inno setup script named [project-name].iss and placed it in `app\src\main\deploy\package\windows\[project-name].iss`.

My maven plugin code looks like

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>package-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>
                    ${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javapackager
                </executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-createjar</argument>
                    <argument>-appclass</argument>
                    <argument>${app.main.class}</argument>
                    <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                    <argument>
                        ${project.build.directory}/classes
                    </argument>
                    <argument>-outdir</argument>
                    <argument>./target</argument>
                    <argument>-outfile</argument>
                    <argument>
                        ${project.artifactId}-app
                    </argument>
                    <argument>-v</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>package-jar2</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>
                    ${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javapackager
                </executable>

                <arguments>
                    <argument>-deploy</argument>
                    <argument>-native</argument>
                    <argument>installer</argument>
                    <argument>-appclass</argument>
                    <argument>${app.main.class}</argument>
                    <argument>-srcfiles</argument>
                    <argument>
                        ${project.build.directory}/${artifactId}-app.jar
                    </argument>
                    <argument>-outdir</argument>
                    <argument>./target</argument>
                    <argument>-outfile</argument>
                    <argument>
                        ${project.artifactId}-app
                    </argument>
                    <argument>-v</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And [project-name].iss file looks like

```
[Setup]
AppName=Project Name
AppId=ProjectName
AppVersion=0.1.0
AppPublisher=Project Name
AppPublisherURL=http://www.todo.com/
AppSupportURL=http://www.todo.com/
AppUpdatesURL=http://www.todo.com/
MinVersion=5.1
DefaultDirName={pf}\Project Name
DefaultGroupName=Project Name
AllowNoIcons=yes
Compression=lzma2/ultra
InternalCompressLevel=ultra
SolidCompression=yes
SetupIconFile=icon.ico
AllowCancelDuringInstall=false
```

But after maven package I'm getting executable file which doesn't have any properties from above inno setup script.(I also placed icon.ico file in `app\src\main\deploy\package\windows\icon.ico`)

Output log while packaging app (It's taking defaults not using [project-name].iss script configuration)
[image]

So can you help me any configuration I'm missing in maven plugin or anything else?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @GhiOm I already implemented it on my project using JavaFX Maven Plugin(same you mentioned). :) But I'm busy from last few days so I didn't get time to post solution I will post it soon.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [JavaPackager Maven Plugin](https://github.com/fvarrui/JavaPackager). It doesn't depend on `javapackager` tool.

Your POM will only have to contain something like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.github.fvarrui</groupId>
    <artifactId>javapackager</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.4</version>    
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>package</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <name>ProjectName</name>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
                <url>http://www.todo.com/</url>
                <mainClass>${app.main.class}</mainClass>
                <bundleJre>true</bundleJre>
                <iconFile>src/main/deploy/package/windows/icon.ico</iconFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and the plugin will generate an installer for your app with a bundled and customized JRE. It'll do all the work for you, so you don't have to worry about any ISS file.

Comment: It is a problem with this one, because the installer does not add the correct permissions to the installation directory. javapackager will create an installer which will automatically install your application in system partition Program Files folder. The folder created for your application does not have correct rights, so if your program try to create some files (in runtime) on that location, will crash and no error will be displayed. You will have to modify the iss file and add `[DIRS] Name: "{app}"; Permissions: everyone-full` .

Answer (score 1):

*(even if this is an old question, some others might search for this)*

You need to take care of the correct filename, the used appName is responsible for the filename the javapackager is searching for.

As you did not provide some `-name`-parameter, the appName is gathered from the provided main-class (`appclass`-parameter), this is even printed inside that command-log, that `Main.ico` gets used. So you need to add this:

```
<argument>-name</argument>
<argument>${project.artifactId}</argument>
```

This means that the filename of the `.ico`-file has to be `${project.artifactId}.ico` below that `app/src/main/deploy/windows`-folder.